# Do function only if filename src does not include @2x

Tags: jquery

I have this code

```
$('.bodyContent_2ndTier_RHS img, .industriesArticle_mainWrapper img, .blog img , .blogpostLHS img').attr('src', function(_, src) {
return src.replace(/(\.\w+$)/, '@2x$1');
}
```

But I want this to only be executed if the attr src DOES NOT ALREADY include @2x.

Please advise on how to achieve this

Comment: I just updated my answer to your original question to address this.

Comment: Please don't do double posts. Make up your mind *before* you post your question.

Comment: Thanks Alnitak - sorry - i thought you had finished answering the other question - hence this new post